# Compressing an associate array using an internal dictionary/lookup-table

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, compression, associative-array

I have an associate array which I would like to compress. 
I was thinking of using an internal dictionary to map the keys of the original array(and possibly values too) to custom smaller values so that the compressed array will use lesser memory.

For instance, 
if my uncompressed array is

```
   {
   apple = 11,
   orange = 32,
   vegetables = 
      {
      carrot = 12,
      onion  = 10,
      }
    }
```

What I would like as a compressed output array for the above input array is :

```
{
[1] = 11,
[2] = 32,
[3] = { [4] = 12, [5] = 10},
}
```

where I will be having an internal dictionary for expanding this array further 
like

```
internal_dictionary = 
 {
 [1] = "apple",
 [2] = "orange",
 [3] = "vegetables",
 [4] = "carrot",
 [5] = "onion",
 }
```

The above is just a very basic 1-to-1 replacement compression. I am guessing there might be other tricks to further optimize the compression.

I can do this manually, but I would like to know if there is any standard algorithm for performing this array compression.

Comment: Have you considered piping it through some zip-stream? Sounds like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What does "piping it through some zip-stream" mean?  Just zip-compressing the entire thing?

Comment: Yes. I mean look at your `{ [1] = 11, .... }` result. It's composed of what, 15, different symbols? That can still be compressed tremendously.

Comment: Are you suggesting to just zip-compress the entire array (or) to compress using my suggested method of array-compression and then zip-compress it? If it is the former, wouldn't having a internal dictionary significantly improve compression?

Comment: Depends on the shape of your input, but my bet is that your average compression algorithm will basically do the replacement that you suggest along with other things. Just save your json data in a file and zip it to see if it meets your requirements. Then do the same but with your dictionary replacement thingy included to see if it helps further.

Comment: Ok. I will do some testing and see how it goes. 
To add more details to my original question, my associative array data is the Game State of a Multiplayer game, which is to be sent by the server some 10 times per second. Hence the need for compression.